# Jqgrid: Access Selected Row Cell value in Code behind

Tags: vb.net, jqgrid

I want to access the selected row cell id in the code behind. I can do it either by Ajax call but it is not possible when i try to send the data from the Jqgrid Subgrid.

**Below is the Subgrid code:**

```js
 subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {

              debugger;
              var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
              var selected_row_id = $('#tblFormData').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'Category_Id')
              // pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
              $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
              $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                 // $("#tblTest").jqGrid({
                      url: "/Forms.aspx/GetFormsData", //?selected_row_id=" + selected_row_id,
                      data: '{"CategoryDesc":"' + selected_row_id + '"}',
                      datatype: "json",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      loadonce: true,
                      width: "300",
                      height: "auto",
                      pager:"#tblSubpager",
                      colNames: ['FormName','FormPath'],
                      colModel: [
                                     { name: "FormName", index: "FormName", editable: true, formatter: 'showlink' },
                                     //{ name: "FormPath", index: "FormPath", editable: true, hidden: true },
                         {
                             name: 'FormPath',
                             index: 'FormPath',
                             hidden: true,
                             enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                             editable: true,
                             edittype: 'file',
                             editrules: {
                                 edithidden: true,
                                 required: true
                             },
                             formoptions: {
                                 elmsuffix: '*'
                             }
                         }
                 
                      ],
                      gridview: true,
                      autoencode: true,
                      ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                      serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                          return JSON.stringify(postData);
                      },
                      jsonReader: {
                          root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
                          page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                          total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                          records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; }
                      }
              });
```

**below is the function which i call it from the URL in Vb.NET.**

```js
  <WebMethod> _
     <ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Shared Function GetFormsData(CategoryId As String) As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))


        Using dt As DataTable = DirectCast(DataAccess.ExecuteStoredProcedure("AFI_DYNAMIC", "Ashley.dbo.usp_GetDownloadFormsDetails", DataAccess.StoredProcedureReturnType.DataTable), DataTable)
            Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim rows1 As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
            Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
            Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            Dim row1 As Dictionary(Of String, String)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                row1 = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
                For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
                    'string sb = "<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\" title=\"Yahoo!\">Yahoo!</a>";
                Next
                rows.Add(row)
                'For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim sb As String = "<a href=" & """" & dr("FormPath").ToString() & """" & ">" & dr("FormName").ToString() & "</a>"
                'Next
                row1.Add(dt.Columns(0).Caption, sb)
                rows1.Add(row1)

            Next
            Return rows1
        End Using
    End Function
```

**Now i want to Access the CategoryId in my code behind  Can anybody help me on this.**

Comment: Hi @Oleg, i have referred lot of examples at final i confused and nothing helps me at all. I saw that you mentioned use postData for jqgrid call. But nothing worked out. could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code have clear many problems. I post below some clear problems which I could find by reading of the code:

- Is `CategoryId` the column of the *parent* grid? Is `$('#tblFormData')` the parent grid? In the case you could use `$(this)` instead of `$('#tblFormData')`.
- You use `pager_id` as `id` of `<div>` of the pager for subgrid, but the line which assign the value for `pager_id` is commented and id is `undefined`. Instead of that you use `pager:"#tblSubpager"` which is wrong.
- jqGrid has no `contentType` parameter. So you should remove it. Instead of that you use already `ajaxGridOptions` parameter with `contentType`. It's correct parameter.
- You use `data: '{"CategoryDesc":"' + selected_row_id + '"}',` but the server code expect parameter with the name `CategoryId` and not `CategoryDesc`. By the way jqGrid has no `data` parameter in case of usage `datatype: "json"`. What you mean should be `postData`. Correct will be to use

```js
postData: {
    CategoryId: selected_row_id
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg i have added below answer for as my comments. Something wrong in my code i know. But it is taking my lot of time to dig into it.

Comment: @Parthhu: You code still contains the bug with the pager which I described in my answer. About sending of parameter: you should add `mtype: "POST"` as additional option to subgrid to use HTTP POST instead GET. It's required if you use `serializeGridData: function (postData) {return JSON.stringify(postData);}`. `UseHttpGet:=True` need be removed in the case too. Alternatively you can remove `serializeGridData` or to use `serializeGridData: function (postData) {return {CategoryId: JSON.stringify(selected_row_id) }; }` without any `postData`.

Comment: @Parthhu: In any way if you need to POST the data to WebMetod you should encode the data like `JSON.stringify({CategoryId: selected_row_id})`. If you need to use HTTP GET then you need to use `{CategoryId: JSON.stringify(selected_row_id)}` instead. In some cases (depend on the type of `selected_row_id`, for example if it would be *integer*) `JSON.stringify(selected_row_id)` is the same as `selected_row_id`. In the cases you can just use `{CategoryId: selected_row_id}`

Comment: Yes @Oleg, it is just a simple integer and i have tried as you said. I have added Stringify and all. wonder It is not hitting anyway. It is only contains "1" as value.

Comment: you declared `CategoryId As String` so it's not an integer. You should use `{CategoryId: JSON.stringify(selected_row_id)}`. If you would declare `CategoryId` as integer then `{CategoryId: selected_row_id}` (`{CategoryId: 1}` will work too). Do you tried to use HTTP POST like I described before? It's the standard way for WebMethod. I recommend you to use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see HTTP traffic. It helps to understand what you send to the server.

Comment: Your awesome @Oleg. Thanks a lot. I have used HTTP POST also. But i have not used data like you mentioned. Anyway my problem solved.